# Count from List(of List(of myObject))

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of lists (StoreList). I need a count of all available apples across all stores. Not sure how to do that.

```
Class myObject
    Public What As String
    Public Available As Boolean
End Class

Public Sub Test()

    Dim ItemList As New List(Of myObject)
    ItemList.Add(New myObject With {.What = "Apple", .Available = True})
    ItemList.Add(New myObject With {.What = "Cherry", .Available = False})

    Dim StoreList As New List(Of List(Of myObject))
    StoreList.Add(ItemList)
    'StoreList.Add(...)

    'error here
    Dim count As Integer = StoreList.Sum( _
            ItemList.Where(Function(x As myObject) _
                   x.What = "Apple" And x.Available).Count)


End Sub
```

Obviously I can't sum a count the way I'm doing it. How would I use Linq to get a count of all available apples across all stores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to assign the function in the `Sum`
try this:

```
Dim count As Integer = StoreList.Sum( Function(inner) _
        inner.Where(Function(x As myObject) _
               x.What = "Apple" And x.Available).Count)
```